High CPU Usage Due to gst-plugin-scan on Ubuntu 22.04 Startup
I am currently facing a performance issue with my Ubuntu system at startup. Each time I boot up my laptop, the CPU usage spikes significantly. Upon investigating the processes through the top command, I noticed that the gst-plugin-scan process is consistently taking up 100% of the CPU resources.
This high CPU usage is causing my system to slow down considerably, making it difficult to work efficiently. I suspect that this issue is related to the GStreamer plugins being scanned during the startup process.
I would appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to:

Remove or uninstall the gst-plugin-scan process or the relevant package(s) associated with it.
Alternatively, if removing the package is not recommended, how can I prevent gst-plugin-scan from running at startup to avoid the CPU spike?

xYour assistance in resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your support.

Are you able to trace the chain of processes that are invoking gst-plugin-scan? For example if you have installed pstree then something like pstree -s $(pgrep -n gst-plugin-scan) might be helpful

@steeldriver I've noticed the similar behavior on Ubuntu 20.04 in Nautilus. The performance spike due to gst-plugin-scan process was very short, couple of seconds. pstree -s $(pgrep -n gst-plugin-scan) gives the following output: systemd───systemd───run-nautilus───nautilus───bwrap───bwrap───totem-video-thu───gst-plugin-scan
